# Immediate Disconnection using websocket in FireFox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've been working on browser extensions that interact with a local application running a WebSocket server.
Safari and Chrome Extensions were very easy to implement, and after some headache getting a feel for FF development, I thought I would be able to implement WebSockets as I had in the other browsers.  However I have had some issues.

I understand that I can't directly create a WebSocket in the "main" js file, and so attempted to use workarounds I found on the internet:

https://github.com/canuckistani/Jetpack-Websocket-Example uses a page-worker as a sort of proxy between main and the WebSocket code.  When I implement this code, my WebSocket connection immediately errors w/ {"isTrusted":true} as the only information.

I also tried to use a hiddenframe as it appears this is how 1Password deals with websocket communication in their FF Addon, but this also results in the same immediate error.

When I simply open a websocket connection to my server in my normal FF instance, it connects perfectly, but so far, I haven't gotten anything to work from addon.

making pageWorker with:

```
var pw = pageWorker.Page({
    contentUrl: self.data.url('com.html'),
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url('com.js')
})
```

com.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

com.js:

```
document.onready = launchCom();
// Could this need to be on ready?

function launchCom() {
    console.log("[com.js] launchCom Called");
    var wsAvailable = false;
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        console.log("[com.js] Detected Websocket in Window, attempting to open...");
        // WebSocket is supported.
        ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9001');
        wsAvailable = true;
    } else {
        console.log("[com.js] Websocket is not supported, upgrade your browser!");
    }
}

ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(event.data);
}

ws.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log("[com.js] ws opened. evt: " + evt);
}

ws.onerror = function(evt) {
    console.log("[com.js] ws error: " + JSON.stringify(evt));
}
```

Running this results in:

```
console.log: xxx: [com.js] launchCom Called
console.log: xxx: [com.js] Detected Websocket in Window, attempting to open...
console.log: xxx: [com.js] ws error: {"isTrusted":true}
console.log: xxx: [com.js] ws closed. evt: {"isTrusted":true}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem:

I'm using https://github.com/zwopple/PocketSocket in my OS X application as my server, and there appears to be an issue with PocketSocket and FF.

After changing PocketSocket's PSWebSocketDriver.m line 87 code from

```
[[headers[@"Connection"] lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"upgrade"]
```

to

```
[[headers[@"Connection"] lowercaseString] containsString:@"upgrade"]
```

per https://github.com/zwopple/PocketSocket/issues/34,
I was able to open a WebSocket connection from FF addon using the original code, but the server errored on messages.

Setting network.websocket.extensions.permessage-deflate to false in about:config allowed messages to be sent so I added

```
 require("sdk/preferences/service").set("network.websocket.extensions.permessage-deflate", false);
```

to my main.js and everthing is working!

The tiny change to PocketSocket's code hasn't had any effects on the server interacting with other WebSocket clients.

Answer (score 0):

I also got stuck in similar situation as websocket can't be implemented directly in main.js. I also did the same as you did , may be server is refusing connection. Snippet from my code look like below :

main.js

```
var wsWorker = require('sdk/page-worker').Page({
  contentURL: "./firefoxScript/webSocket.html",
  contentScriptFile : ["./firefoxScript/webSocket.js"]
});
```

webSocket.html

```
<html>
<head>        
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

webSocket.js

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9451'); 
  ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('Connection open...');
};

ws.onclose = function() {
  console.log('Connection closed...');
};

ws.onmessage = function(event) {
   console.log('Message recieved...');
};

ws.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log('Connection Error...');
};
```

It's perfectly working fine for me.